# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] controller_name/fusioncharts.widgets.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fusioncharts

Hello community I'm implementing Fusion Charts in my rails application. I followed all the steps guided in the installation of fusion charts with rails by keeping all the `js` files in `vendor/assets/javascripts`. After refreshing the page I can see the div gots populated but with the error `Chart type not supported`. Once I kept the `js` files in `app/assets/javascripts` it **works**. But not from vendor path. Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think

Adding all required JS files in `assets/javascript/application.js`  will fix the problem.

e.g.

In file `assets/javascript/application.js`

```
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widgets
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts.maps
//= require fusioncharts/maps/fusioncharts.usa
//= require fusioncharts/maps/fusioncharts.world
//= require fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion
```

Do let me know if this solves the issue.